# Android service to detect if another application is running

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there any action like `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` to track if a specific application is launched? Any help will be appreciated!

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
// Do something 
} else if (// application XYZ started) {
// Do something Else 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can see if application is running:

```
ActivityManager activity_manager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
final   ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)       getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
final List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks    (Integer.MAX_VALUE);
for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++) 
{
    Log.d("Executed app", "Application executed : " +recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString()+ "\t\t ID: "+recentTasks.get(i).id+"");         
}
```

and if application is foreground:

```
public static boolean isForeground(Context ctx, String myPackage){
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > runningTaskInfo = manager.getRunningTasks(1); 

ComponentName componentInfo = runningTaskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
if(componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(myPackage)) {
    return true;
}       
return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however this solution allows me to know if a specific application is running at a specific point of time, so I need to run this code every 10 sec -for example- to check if the desired application is started or not..
What I'm looking for is an event that this application has launched so I can do something before starting it like prevent it from start or ask for password...